# c so built in centos 5.3 loaded in centos 6.3

Tags: c, linker, cross-platform, shared-libraries

I have two projects:
project1, builds target of libA.so
project2, builds target of exeB, which leverages libA.so

If project1 is built in CentOS 5.3, and libA.so is copied from CentOS 5.3 to CentOS 6.3. Then build project2 in the CentOS 6.3 machine. Is it expected that exeB and libA.so work well?

A similar question is, if project1 is built in 32-bit CentOS 6.3, and libA.so is copied from 32-bit CentOS 6.3 to 64-bit CentOS 6.3. Then build project2 in the 64-bit CentOS 6.3 machine. Is it expected that exeB and libA.so work well?

Answer (score 0):

As I observe, it's OK. But I'm wondering whether there's any potential risk of doing so, i.e. running executable binary in one system but was but built in a different system with different OS version, OS bits, etc.